# PySide6 QThread different behavior in PyCharm debug mode

Tags: python, multithreading, pycharm, pyside, qthread

I'm trying to use QThreads to do some long calculations in the background while the Ui is still running. I noticed that my threads just werent working properly when I run the program in PyCharm debug mode. Here is a minimal example:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, QThread


class Worker(QObject):

    def work(self):
        while True:
            print("working")



if __name__ == "__main__":

    thread = QThread()
    worker = Worker()

    worker.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(worker.work)

    thread.start()

    while True:
        print("do other stuff")
```

When I run this code without debug mode, it prints "working" and "do other stuff" repeatedly. When I run it in debug mode, it only prints "do other stuff". The work method isn't called at all. What is going on here? I'm using PySide 6.5.0 and python 3.10.

Comment: What do you mean by "debug mode"?

Comment: pycharm's debug mode. I'm not sure how it works under the hood but I assume there is some sort of standard python debugger for stepping through the program and setting breakpoints.

Comment: Then it must be a bug/limitation specific to pycharm. I suggest you direct your question towards the pycharm devs.

Comment: Note that when using a standard QThread (without overriding `run()`), it uses an event loop, and that can only work properly with an existing QApplication instance.

Comment: I may have found a solution... Apparently turning off pycharm's qt compatibility fixes the issue... Now I'm scared something else is gonna break though.

Comment: The particular example in the question will work okay without an event-loop because it doesn't use cross-thread signals. However, if the worker emitted signals that were connected to a slot in the main thread, then those signals would never be received. That in itself wouldn't stop anything else working as normal, though.